# Reprojecting each tif located in Folder Directory using GDAL in Python

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, for-loop

Python beginner here. I am using python to reproject a folder of rasters (.tifs). Each raster has a projection that I want to change to WGS 1984 (espg:4326). I want to use an open-source GIS library rather than ESRI's ArcPy library. I'm assuming this needs to occur with a loop going through my folder directory and reprojecting each raster one by one.

My current lines of code read:

```
newpath = 'path to my folder' 
for raster in os.listdir(newpath):
    gdal.Warp(new_filename, raster, dstSRS="+init=epsg:4326")
```

The problem I'm attempting to solve is how to correctly specify the output filename of each raster in the `gdal.Warp` line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save the reprojected raster in the same dir and call it `/path/to/newpath/raster_reproj.tif`:

```
newpath = 'path to my folder' 
for raster in os.listdir(newpath):
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(raster)
    old_raster = os.path.join(newpath, raster)
    new_raster = os.path.join(newpath, f"{basename}_reproj{extension}")
    gdal.Warp(new_raster, old_raster, dstSRS="+init=epsg:4326")
```

If you need to save the reprojected raster in a different dir and leave the filename the same:

```
oldpath = 'path to my folder with data' 
newpath = 'path to my folder to write reprojected to' 
for raster in os.listdir(oldpath):
    old_raster = os.path.join(oldpath, raster)
    new_raster = os.path.join(newpath, raster)
    gdal.Warp(new_raster, old_raster, dstSRS="+init=epsg:4326")
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly a Python question, not really GIS related

```py
from pathlib import Path

newpath = "tif/input/dir/"
destination_dir = "/else/where/dir/"
for raster in Path(newpath).glob('*.tif'):
    dest_file = Path(destination_dir).joinpath(f"{raster.stem}_4326.tif")
    gdal.Warp(f"{dest_file}", f"{raster}", dstSRS="+init=epsg:4326")
```

See https://pymotw.com/3/pathlib/ or https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/ among other `pathlib` tutorials (`os` module approach can be used but is not recommended nowadays)